# getting the following error when using firestore Error: FIRESTORE (8.1.2) INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED: Unexpected state

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo

I'm currently working on an app and it was working fine for awhile...when I was signing up I add the users to firestore and it still worked but now whenever I use firestore in some other screen it keeps throwing the following error:

```
 @firebase/firestore:, Firestore (8.1.2): FIRESTORE (8.1.2) INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED: Unexpected state

Stack trace:
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LogBox/LogBox.js:148:8 in registerError
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LogBox/LogBox.js:59:8 in errorImpl
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LogBox/LogBox.js:33:4 in console.error
  node_modules/expo/build/environment/react-native-logs.fx.js:27:4 in error
  http://127.0.0.1:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:171277:27
```

and this is the code of the screen in which I'm getting errors

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  TextInput,
  ScrollView,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Modal,
  Platform,
  ToastAndroid,
  Alert,
} from 'react-native';
import DropDownPicker from 'react-native-dropdown-picker';
import { FontAwesome5, FontAwesome, Entypo } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import firebase from 'firebase';
import db from '../Config/Firebase';
import { CheckBox } from 'react-native-elements';
import Constants from 'expo-constants'

export default class Add extends React.Component{
    state = {
        allVisitsCompleted: false,
        patientId: Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000000) + 1,
        patientName: '',
        age: '',
        address: '',
        phoneNumber: '',
        mobileNumber: '',
        gender: '',
        visitDate: '',
        date: null,
        modalVisible: false,
        teethNumberModalVisible: false,
        patient: [],
        addPressed: false,
        patientAdded: false,
      };

      onAddPatient = async () => {
    firebase.firestore().collection("Patients").add({
        patientName:this.state.patientName
    })
}

    render(){
        var patientName = this.state.patientName
        var patientId = this.state.patientId

        return(
            <ScrollView style={{ backgroundColor: '#F5FFFA' }}>
                <View style={{ marginHorizontal: 19, marginTop: Constants.statusBarHeight}}>
          <Text style={styles.header}>Patient name</Text>
          <TextInput
            placeholder=""
            style={{
              fontSize: 20,
              fontWeight: '400',
              height: 25,
              borderBottomWidth: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth,
              marginTop: 5,
            }}
            value={this.state.patientName}
            onChangeText={(patientName) =>
              this.setState({ patientName: patientName })
            }
          />
        </View>

        <View style={{ marginHorizontal: 19, marginTop: 20 }}>
          <Text style={styles.header}>Patient ID</Text>
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 20 }}>{patientId}</Text>
        </View>

        <View style={{ marginHorizontal: 19, marginTop: 20 }}>
          <Text style={styles.header}>Age</Text>
          <TextInput
            placeholder=""
            style={{
              fontSize: 20,
              fontWeight: '400',
              height: 25,
              borderBottomWidth: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth,
              marginTop: 5,
            }}
            value={this.state.age}
            onChangeText={(age) => this.setState({ age: age })}
          />
        </View>

        <View style={{ marginHorizontal: 19, marginTop: 20 }}>
          <Text style={styles.header}>Address</Text>
          <TextInput
            placeholder=""
            style={{
              fontSize: 20,
              fontWeight: '400',
              height: 25,
              borderBottomWidth: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth,
              marginTop: 5,
            }}
            value={this.state.address}
            onChangeText={(address) => this.setState({ address: address })}
          />
        </View>

        <View style={{ marginHorizontal: 19, marginTop: 20 }}>
          <Text style={styles.header}>Mobile number</Text>
          <TextInput
            placeholder=""
            style={{
              fontSize: 20,
              fontWeight: '400',
              height: 25,
              borderBottomWidth: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth,
              marginTop: 5,
            }}
            value={this.state.mobileNumber}
            onChangeText={(mobileNumber) =>
              this.setState({ mobileNumber: mobileNumber })
            }
          />
        </View>

        <View style={{ marginHorizontal: 19, marginTop: 20 }}>
          <Text style={styles.header}>Phone number</Text>
          <TextInput
            placeholder=""
            style={{
              fontSize: 20,
              fontWeight: '400',
              height: 25,
              borderBottomWidth: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth,
              marginTop: 5,
            }}
            value={this.state.phoneNumber}
            onChangeText={(phoneNumber) =>
              this.setState({ phoneNumber: phoneNumber })
            }
          />
        </View>

        <View style={{ marginHorizontal: 19, marginTop: 20 }}>
          <Text style={styles.header}>Gender</Text>
          <TextInput
            placeholder=""
            style={{
              fontSize: 20,
              fontWeight: '400',
              height: 25,
              borderBottomWidth: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth,
              marginTop: 5,
            }}
            value={this.state.gender}
            onChangeText={(gender) => this.setState({ gender: gender })}
          />
        </View>

        <View style={{ marginHorizontal: 19, marginTop: 20 }}>
          <Text style={styles.header}>All visits completed</Text>
          <CheckBox
            checkedColor="#0F0"
            checkedTitle="Yes"
            onPress={() =>
              this.setState({
                allVisitsCompleted: !this.state.allVisitsCompleted,
              })
            }
            size={30}
            title="No"
            uncheckedColor="#F00"
            checked={this.state.allVisitsCompleted}
            checkedIcon="check"
            uncheckedIcon="close"
          />
        </View>

        <View style={{ marginHorizontal: 25, marginVertical: 20 }}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={{
              alignItems: 'center',
              backgroundColor: '#62C7A1',
              padding: 10,
              borderRadius: 20,
            }}
            onPress={() => {
              this.onAddPatient();
              this.setState({ addPressed: true });
            }}>
            {this.state.patientAdded === true ? (
              <PacmanIndicator color="#FFF" size={30} />
            ) : (
              <Text
                style={{
                  fontSize: 20,
                  color: 'white',
                  fontWeight: 'bold',
                  textTransform: 'uppercase',
                }}>
                Add
              </Text>
            )}
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
            </ScrollView>
        )
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    header: {
      fontSize: 13,
      fontWeight: '200',
      color: '#8e93a1',
      textTransform: 'uppercase',
    },
    chooseDate: {
      fontSize: 13, 
      fontWeight: '600',
      color: '#696969',
      textTransform: 'uppercase',
    },
  });
```

If you have any Idea how to fix this please let me know...Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this might be a synchronicity issue, as your `onAddPatient` function is an async function but you are not awaiting firestore to add the documents, which generates an unexpected state. To fix it you just need to await for it, so:

```
onAddPatient = async () => {
    await firebase.firestore().collection("Patients").add({
        patientName:this.state.patientName
    })
}
```

Comment: Hey! The solution that you gave worked for me but now I'm getting the same error for some other screen. I personally think it is because of the onSnapshot function...I will add that code to the question...but however thank you so much!

Comment: @Vibha I see that this is your 1st post on stack, so first of all, welcome. I would advise you to post this as a separate question, since now the answer I provided, which you mentioned was correct, is no longer valid cause you changed the code of the question and if someone else in the community goes through the same issue, they won't be able to see how to apply the solution because of that. If you want to make a followup question with more code that's fine you can do it (although better to post a separate question), but you have to keep the original code.

Comment: additionally you can read this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for what to do when someone answers your question.

Comment: Thank you so much @Rafael Lemos

Comment: Please consider accepting/upvoting the answer if it solved the issue you were facing.

Comment: I did upvote your answer but it just says "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score." I don't know what to do

Comment: I guess you figured out by yourself, sorry for the delay in replying. again, welcome to Stack Overflow's community.

Comment: No problem...Thank you so much too!